# javascript: truncate object properties in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, say the object looks like following:

```
var row = {
    data: 'test',
   text: 'test'
};
```

I want to loop through the array and just get the object with text property.
What is the best way to do it?
So, I want to loop and the object should look like: `row = {text: 'test'}`

I tried something like below without luck:

```
arr.forEach(function (item){ //arr is the array of object
     return {text: item.text};
});
```

Comment: >I want to loop through the array and just get the object with text property
 -- which one do you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that:

```
var arr = [{
    data: 'testData',
   text: 'testText'
}];

var newArr = arr.map(function(item){
    return {text: item.data};
});
```

The result will look like:

```
[{ text: 'testData' }]
```

If you want it to be `[ {testText: 'testData' }]` then:

```
var arr = [{
    data: 'testData',
   text: 'testText'
}];

var newArr = arr.map(function(item){
    var obj = {};
    obj[item.text] = item.data;
    return obj;
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As you want a object with single key value pair, you don't need to store in object form. You can save them as an array.

```
var array = [
   {
      text : "text",
      data : "data"
   },
   {
      text : "text1",
      data : "data1"
   }
]

var newArray = array.map(function(item){
    return item.data;
});
```

your output will look like

```
 ['text','text1']
```

Comment: That was just an example, I do need more than one key value pair. sorry for the confusion.